# How to generate random number for whole geometry in geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When I am trying to generate random rotation for geometry, the sockets are not compatible.
How to generate random number here?

[image]

Comment: .. bearing in mind that the components of Euler rotations are in Radians, so if you want  a random angle  from the full span around any axis, that would be something with a range of `2*pi`. ( `-pi -> pi`... `0 -> tau`... etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this, with an [Attribute Statistic](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_statistic.html) node :

[image]

Note I'm using a Mesh Line node with a count set to 1 to instantiate a single vertex so the field is evaluated only once to avoid potentially costly computations.

If you want to simplify things afterwards you can select the leftmost three nodes and *Node > Make Group* or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd>. Then link the group input to the seed, min and max to have a reusable node group.

[image]

[image]

Then if you want to spawn a new group instance, go to *Add > Group > Group Name*.

Answer (score 5):

one way to achieve what you want is this node setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Do you think that there should be a node to generate Random value for whole geometry? Or, does it not make sense have such node?

Comment: I am not sure about it. I think the developers must have had something in mind.